# Splitting String gives an out of bounds exception

Tags: java, arrays, string, split, indexoutofboundsexception

I need to get rid of all the punctuation from the sentence (str), but when I split the string and try to check each index it throws an exception

```
String str = "RT @GHCheer2015: Freshman & Sophomores: Interested in cheer at GH? Email: jackemersoncheer@gmail.com";
      String punct = ",./;:'\"?<>[]{}|`~!@#$%^&*()";
      String finaltext = "";
      System.out.println(str);
      String[] arr3 = str.split("");
      for(int k = 0; k < arr3.length; k++){
         for(int i = 0; i < punct.length(); i++){
            if((arr3[k].charAt(k)+"") != (punct.charAt(i)+""))
               finaltext += arr[k].charAt(k) + "";
         }
      }
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at StringMethods.main(StringMethods.java:109)
```

Comment: You split on every letter, and then you call `.charAt(k)` on the one letter `String`. When `k` is more than `0` it goes out of bounds

Comment: Also don't compare `String`'s with `!=` or `==`, use `.equals()`

Comment: `String newString = str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z 0-9]", "").replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " ").trim();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay try this,

Optimized solution :)

```
public static void main(String args[]) 
{

    String str = "RT @GHCheer2015: Freshman & Sophomores: Interested in cheer at GH? Email: jackemersoncheer@gmail.com";
      String punct = ",./;:'\"?<>[]{}|`~!@#$%^&*()";
      System.out.println(str);

      String[] punctArr = punct.split("");

         for(int i = 0; i < punctArr.length; i++){
             str = str.replace(punctArr[i], "");
         }

      System.out.println("Final string \n :" + str);
}
```

Comment: replaceAll needs regex !!

Answer (score 1):

If removing all the punctuation is what you want to achieve, you can simply do this :

```
str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z 0-9]", "").replaceAll("\\s+", " ").trim();
```

Same is pointed out by @DevilsHnd in the comments

Answer (score 0):

Problem is `arr3[k].charAt(k)`. arr3[k] gives you a single character string thus can have index only 0. the time you find index >0 (k>0 in this case) it will throw StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.
Instead you can use string contains method to find solution to your problem.

```
        String punct = ",./;:'\"?<>[]{}|`~!@#$%^&*()";
        String finaltext = "";
        System.out.println(str);
        String[] arr3 = str.split("");
        for (int k = 0; k < arr3.length; k++) {
            if (!punct.contains(arr3[k])) {
                finaltext += arr3[k] + "";
            }
        }
    }
```